# Hyperlink PDF using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to make my excel spreadsheet insert a hyperlink to a PDF but only display the last five characters of the name eg: helpme12345 and the cell show 12345 as the clickable link. I can do this long winded but am hoping a VBA macro can do this quicker

How can I write this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can solve it at all like that. Not even by using VBA. Either the entire cell is a hyperlink, or it's not.

But I'll provide you with a neat trick:

1. Enter your text in a cell and make it as big as you need. For example "Click here to read more". Edit the cell again (press F2) and underline the word "here". Add some font colour as well if you want
2. Now draw a rectangular box that covers the word "here" (`Insert --> Shapes --> some rectangular box`)
3. Right-click on the rectangle and define your hyperlinke
4. Finally: Make the box transparent without borders. It'll still be there, but it's invisible... BUT clickable! It looks like you click on the word, but it's the box you click on.